# Ajax: Pulling nested variables from json line

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I would like to pull specific values from a json line (cownumber,weight,height)

The JSON looks like this when accessed from the url using Postman

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "cownumber": "1234",
      "weight": 300,
      "height": 25
    },
    "type": "master_animal"
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "/master_animal/1234"
  }
}
```

I use a function to extract the cownumber from the URL

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
</script>
```

Then with that cownumber, I want to pull the json line from a different url

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){
        var cownumber = getQueryVariable("cownumber")
        $.ajax({
                url: '/api/master_animal/'+cownumber,
                data: {},
                type: 'GET',
                datatype : 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var height = $(data['height']);
                    var weight = $(data['weight']);

                    $('#cownumber').val(cownumber);
                    $('#height').val(height);
                    $('#weight').val(weight);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });

      });
    });
</script>
```

On my website, I want it to display the cownumber, weight, and height. But all it displays is the cownumber(because it pulled that variable from the getQueryVariable function). For height and weight it displays "[Object object]"

[Picture of website side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoNdp.png)

I am not sure if what is the best method to pull the necessary variable from the json line. I am not even entirely convinced that the function is actually getting the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are accessing your data wrong. Just because your variable is named `data` does not mean that your access to the data is already at the `data` property. Meaning you need to access the data like so

```
var height = data.data.attributes.height;
```

Also you do not need to wrap your values in jQuery. Just get the value and use it

```
var height = data.data.attributes.height;
$('#height').val(height);
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested but got a different error                  "caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"

Comment: @samueloyeleye, Then your JSON structure isn't what you posted. `console.log(data)` to log your `data` variable and make sure it contains what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that ?

```
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){
        let cownumber = getQueryVariable("cownumber")
        $.ajax({
                url: '/api/master_animal/'+cownumber,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    data = response['data']['attributes'];
                    let height = $(data['height']);
                    let weight = $(data['weight']);

                    $('#cownumber').val(cownumber);
                    $('#height').val(height);
                    $('#weight').val(weight);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `height` and `weight` properties are further nested in your response object, inside of the `attributes`:

```
success: function(response) {
  var height = response.data.attributes.height;
  var weight = response.data.attributes.weight;

  $('#cownumber').val(cownumber);
  $('#height').val(height);
  $('#weight').val(weight);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this utils function to extract any value from a nested object.

```
getValueAtPath(obj, path, def){

    if(!obj) return def;

    path = path.split('.');
    let i, len;
    len = path.length;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return def;
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    }

    if (obj === undefined) return def;

    return obj;
}
```

In your case, to get `cownumber`, `weight`, `height`, you would simply do

```
let cowNumber = getValueatPath(jsonData, 'data.attributs.cownumber', defualtvalue) 

let height = getValueatPath(jsonData, 'data.attributs.height', defualtvalue) 

let weight = getValueatPath(jsonData, 'data.attributs.weight', defualtvalue)
```

Hope this helps;